# Ordinalize in embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, view

Is there a quick way to be able to ordinalize the following code?

```
<%= time_tag(Date.today, :format=>'%A %d %b') %>
```

The current output reads

```
Tuesday 18 Feb
```

I want to ordinalize the date to show

```
Tuesday 18th Feb
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write as below using [`#ordinalize`](http://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/ordinalize) :

```
<%= time_tag(Date.today, :format=>"%A #{Date.today.day.ordinalize} %b") %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Date::DATE_FORMATS` to add a new customized format, and `Integer.ordinalize` to get the day ordinal:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:month_ordinal] = lambda { |date| 
  date.strftime("%A #{date.day.ordinalize}, %B") 
}

>> Date.today.to_formatted_s(:month_ordinal)
=> "Tuesday 18th, Feb"
```